# cakephp 2.x saveAll with 2 primaryKey

Tags: cakephp-2.0

My table has 2 column: `cid` AND `code`

Both of them are primary keys, `cid` is primary key 1, `code` is primary key 2

I am using `cakephp` and i'm trying to save the data with:

```
cid [1, 2, 1, 2]

code [11, 11, 12, 12]
```

But i receive error message:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Please help me, many thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as two primary keys. Share your table definition.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a php error, what happened here is that you caused a mysql database error and the cake error class is returning that to you. On `saveAll` you are attempting an insert into one of your tables that already has a particular primary key in it. Run these queries to check:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE cid = 1;
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE code = 1;
```

If anything comes up that is the offending record. Delete it and try again. Also you should not be force-ably setting the primary keys of your tables you should use `autoincrement` instead. And I know from experience that cake gives you a hard time with tables that have multiple primary keys. I hope that helps.